# Roblox scripts that no longer exist anywhere in game are appearing as children of newly created characters

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm using a script from the Roblox marketplace that I modified heavily. The original version no longer exists anywhere in any of the game, but is appearing as a child of new characters, although I don't have a script that could put it there. Why is this happening and how do I fix it? I have not found anything like this anywhere else.

Here is the original script:

```
local mouse = game.Players.LocalPlayer:GetMouse()
local running = false

function getTool()  
    for _, kid in ipairs(script.Parent:GetChildren()) do
        if kid.className == "Tool" then return kid end
    end
    return nil
end


mouse.KeyDown:connect(function (key) -- Run function
    key = string.lower(key)
    if string.byte(key) == 48 then
        running = true
        local keyConnection = mouse.KeyUp:connect(function (key)
            if string.byte(key) == 48 then
                running = false
            end
        end)
        for i = 1,5 do
            game.Workspace.CurrentCamera.FieldOfView = (70+(i*2))
            wait()
        end
        game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character.Humanoid.WalkSpeed = 85
        repeat wait () until running == false
        keyConnection:disconnect()
        game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character.Humanoid.WalkSpeed = 16
        for i = 1,5 do
            game.Workspace.CurrentCamera.FieldOfView = (80-(i*2))
            wait()
        end
    end
end)
```

Here is the modified script:

```
wait(1)
local Player = script.Parent
local mouse = game.Players.LocalPlayer:GetMouse()
local running = false
local startSpeed = 10
local Speed = script.Speed
Speed.Value = 10
local Earnings = script.Earnings
Earnings.Value = 25
local Cash = script.Cash
Cash.Value = 10000
local speedUpCost = script.speedUpCost
speedUpCost.Value = 100
local earnUpCost = script.earnUpCost
earnUpCost.Value = 100

game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character.Humanoid.WalkSpeed = Speed.Value

function getTool()  
    for _, kid in ipairs(script.Parent:GetChildren()) do
        if kid.className == "Tool" then return kid end
    end
    return nil
end


mouse.KeyDown:connect(function (key)
    key = string.lower(key)
    if string.byte(key) == 48 then
        running = true
        local keyConnection = mouse.KeyUp:connect(function (key)
            if string.byte(key) == 48 then
                running = false
            end
        end)
        game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character.Humanoid.WalkSpeed = Speed.Value
        repeat wait () until running == false
        keyConnection:disconnect()
        game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character.Humanoid.WalkSpeed = startSpeed
    end
end)
```

Here is the code I'm using to put the modified script and some others as children of new characters: (These other scripts don't include the original script that I modified)

```
function onPlayerEntered(player)
    player.CharacterAdded:connect(function (char)
        local Scripts = script:GetChildren() 
        for i=1,5 do
            local s = Scripts[i]:clone()
            s.Parent = char
            s.Disabled = false
        end     
    end)
end

game.Players.PlayerAdded:connect(onPlayerEntered)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing what scripts are in your explorer, it looks like your problem could be in your onPlayerEntered function. You are iterating over 5 unnamed, possibly random, scripts and inserting them into the Player.

According to https://developer.roblox.com/api-reference/function/Instance/GetChildren, the order of the elements in `script:GetChildren()` depends on the order in which their Parent property was set.
It is probably safer to clone the children explicitly by name, or iterate over the length of the Scripts array.

To debug this, I might recommend modifying your for loop to be :

```
local Scripts = script:GetChildren() 
for i=1,#Scripts,1 do
    local s = Scripts[i]:clone()
    s.Parent = char
    s.Disabled = false
    print("Inserting script : ", s.Name, " - ", s:GetFullName())
end
```

This should help tell you what scripts are actually being added.

Alternatively, you could just add the scripts you want into `StarterPlayer > StarterPlayerScripts` folder, and they will automatically be added to the player when the player joins.